# How to resolve sqlite communication error in java IntelliJ

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to a sql database with java but this isn't really working out. normally people say they have a user and password but I never created anything like that. I downloaded sqlite studio and you can pretty much just make a database without having to create some kind of account but when i'm trying to connect it gives me an error that it can't connect `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`.
How do I resolve this issue? This is the code I have right now:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MyJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JDBC-video");

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from people");

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("firstname"));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 3306 is mysql's port. Sqlite doesn't run like that .sqlite studio is not a db. Do you have mysql running on loclahost?

Comment: I found out that I had to use something completely different because I wasn't using mysql but just an sqlite database file and that made my problem go away.